# How do I get my program to print out all of my input from a do while loop?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm writing a program called CreateGradeReport.java. It is a program designed to prompt the user for student names and numerical grades. The program will stop prompting the user for input when "-1" is entered. When -1 is entered, a grade report will be displayed with the student names and grades (converted to a letter grade), as well as the maximum and minimum grades and the average of all the grades.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CreateGradeReport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String studentName = "";
    int studentGrade = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int min = 100;
    int max = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's name or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentName = input.nextLine();
        if (studentName.equals("-1")){
            break;
            }
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentGrade = input.nextInt();
        if(studentGrade == -1){
            break;
            }
        String dummy = input.nextLine();
        }
    while(!studentName.equals("-1") && studentGrade != -1);
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println("Class Grading Report");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    if(studentGrade >= 90) {
        System.out.println(studentName + ": A");
    }
    else if(studentGrade >=80 && studentGrade < 90) {
        System.out.println(studentName + ": B");
    }
    else if(studentGrade >=70 && studentGrade < 80) {
        System.out.println(studentName + ": C");
    }
    else if(studentGrade >= 60 && studentGrade < 70){
        System.out.println(studentName + ": D");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(studentName + ": F");
    }
    if (studentGrade < min) {
        min = studentGrade;
    }
    if (studentGrade > max) {
        max = studentGrade;
    }
    count++;
    sum += studentGrade;
    
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
    System.out.println("Average: " + sum/count);
}
}
```

I have everything set up correctly except for one thing: I'm unable to print out all the student names and grades individually. Everytime I run the program, I get -1 for the student name and whatever the grade is for the final studentGrade entered. This is the output I've been receiving:

```
Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: Shane B.

Enter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: 99

Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: Megan B.

Enter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: 88

Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: -1
-----------------------
Class Grading Report
-----------------------
-1: B
Minimum: 88
Maximum: 88
Average: 88
```

I need to know how to get it so that I can print out all the input I provided during the do while loop. I'd prefer to do this without creating a separate class or using an ArrayList.

Comment: Without using any sort of list/array type structure, it is impossible. If there's more than one input where can you store them? Why can't you use a list/array? Or is it `ArrayList` specifically that you can't use?

Comment: ArrayList specifically.

Comment: May I ask why? And if you can use other lists, then do you have an issue with implementing it, or were you just looking for data structure recommendations?

Comment: Oh unless you actually wanted to print them as soon as they're inputted? Then you can just print inside the loop as @christianfoleide said

Comment: @HenryTwist - doesn't need to be a list. Both set and map are also options, as are plain arrays.

Comment: Yes @SoftwareEngineer I said "list/array type structure", meaning some sort of collection. The OP seemed to phrase it as if they don't want to store them at all. But regardless, not using `ArrayList` here seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: @Henry Twist The project I'm working on requires it to be done without the use of an array list. Also I need it to print out as soon as I'm done with the do while loop (entering -1)

Comment: Then I would recommend using maybe a `LinkedList` if that really is the only requirement? This gives `O(1)` adds and efficient iteration.

Comment: Although if you're not allowed to use any more classes either and the only inputs are pairs of (student, grade) then maybe a `HashMap`? Then you can use the student names as keys, then iterate over the keyset after the loop is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get -1 for the student name, is because you exit by first storing `-1` in `studentName` (or `studentGrade`), so by the point you are trying to print these to the console, either of them HAS to be `-1`, you can easily see this in your loop condition.

To do this (the way I think you intend to, printing several students to the console), you will have to wrap your entire main method in a loop, but remove the inner one.

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  do {
    System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit: ");
    int i = scanner.nextInt();
    if (i == -1) {
      exit = true;
    }
    ..
    get student specific input here
    ..
    process like you have done before
    ..
    print results

  } while (!exit)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what this should look like? Would the do while loop begin above "public static void main"? Or right after?

Comment: I edited the answer. I understood it as you could not use any sort of implementation of a collection (arrays,maps etc.) based on your discussion above @Henry Twist above, and by then you have no other choice but to print them out individually as-you-go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map, that would make sense in your case. A map where key would be the student name and value the student grade.

```
      import java.util.*;
      public class CreateGradeReport {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Mpa<String, Integer> map = new HashMap() ;
        String studentName = "";
        int studentGrade = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int min = 100;
       int max = 0;
       do {
           System.out.print("\nEnter the student's name or [-1] to quit: ");
          studentName = input.nextLine();
         if (studentName.equals("-1")){
             break;
              }
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentGrade = input.nextInt();
        if(studentGrade == -1){
             break;
             }
       String dummy = input.nextLine();
       map.put(studentName, student Grade) ;
         }
      while(!studentName.equals("-1") && studentGrade != -1);
```

In the end just do `System.out.println(map);`